# Shoot object upward from surface of earth with some initial velocity: Express height as function of time?

Tags: projectile

Say we shoot an object upward from the surface of the earth with some initial velocity.

Then making the usual assumptions (e.g. only force acting on object is earth's gravity), we can find things like the object's maximum height achieved and its escape velocity (11.2 km/s).

I was wondering if we can also express the object's height as a function of time?

I've tried doing this but (after a lot of work with differential equations) managed to get only very complicated expressions of time as a function of the object's height. Even assuming I haven't made any errors, I don't see any way to invert these expressions to get height as a function of time.

(This has almost certainly been done before, so answers could also simply point me to any relevant resources. So far my googling has only ever yielded stuff about the object's maximum height and escape velocity.)

---

FWIW, here's what I've found (which may or may not be correct):

Let $V$ be the initial velocity (at $t=0$), $G$ be the gravitational
constant, $M$ be the earth's mass, $R$ be the earth's radius, $h$ be the object's height (above the earth's surface), $V_{e}$ be the escape velocity. Also, let $$C=\frac{V^{2}}{2GM}-\frac{1}{R}.$$

Then what I've found is this:

$$t=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{C+2}\frac{1}{C}\sqrt{\frac{2}{GM}}\left[\frac{\left(\frac{1}{R+h}+C\right)^{3}-3}{3\left(R+h\right)^{2}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{C}}\ln\frac{\sqrt{C}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{R+h}+C}}{\sqrt{C}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{R+h}+C}}\right]+C_{1}, & \text{for }V>V_{e},\\
\frac{1}{C+2}\frac{1}{C}\sqrt{\frac{2}{GM}}\left[\frac{\left(\frac{1}{R+h}+C\right)^{3}-3}{3\left(R+h\right)^{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left|C\right|}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{R+h}+C}}{\sqrt{\left|C\right|}}\right]+C_{2}, & \text{for }V<V_{e},
\end{cases}$$

where the constants $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ are given by

\begin{alignat*}{1}
C_{1} & =-\frac{1}{C+2}\frac{1}{C}\sqrt{\frac{2}{GM}}\left[\frac{\left(\frac{V^{2}}{\sqrt{2GM}}\right)^{3}-3}{3R^{2}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{C}}\ln\frac{\sqrt{C}+\sqrt{\frac{V^{2}}{\sqrt{2GM}}}}{\sqrt{C}-\sqrt{\frac{V^{2}}{\sqrt{2GM}}}}\right]\\
\\
C_{2} & =-\frac{1}{C+2}\frac{1}{C}\sqrt{\frac{2}{GM}}\left[\frac{\left(\frac{V^{2}}{\sqrt{2GM}}\right)^{3}-3}{3R^{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left|C\right|}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{V^{2}}{\sqrt{2GM}}}}{\sqrt{\left|C\right|}}\right]
\end{alignat*}

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory#Elliptic_trajectory

Comment: Read a little further down: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory#The_radial_Kepler_problem_(distance_as_function_of_time) The inverse function can only be expressed as a series. Your expression for $t$ looks too complicated... a lot more than Wikipedia’s.

Comment: Did you try solving when $V=V_e$? That produces a very simple result that *can* be inverted. Make sure that whatever method you are using matches Wikipedia in this “parabolic” case before figuring out why your “hyperbolic” and “elliptical” solutions don’t seem to match. Note that all these adjectives are referring to *radial* orbits that are *degenerate* parabolas, hyperbolas, and ellipses.

Comment: If $V=V_e$, then I get $$h=\left(3\sqrt{\frac{GM}{2}}t+R^{3/2}\right)^{2/3}-R.$$

Comment: That looks right. The Wikipedia equation measures $t$ from when $r=0$, while you measure it from when $r=R$.